# trying to get radio button in gtk4-rs

Tags: rust

here is an extract of a gtk4 showing how to create radio button in c.

```
GtkWidget *live = gtk_check_button_new_with_label ("Live");
GtkWidget *laugh = gtk_check_button_new_with_label ("Laugh");
GtkWidget *love = gtk_check_button_new_with_label ("Love");


gtk_check_button_set_group (GTK_CHECK_BUTTON (laugh),GTK_CHECK_BUTTON (live));
gtk_check_button_set_group (GTK_CHECK_BUTTON (love), GTK_CHECK_BUTTON (live));
```

I would like to do the same in gtk4 rust

```
let _cb  = CheckButton::builder().label("Laugh").build();
let _cb1 = CheckButton::builder().label("Live").build();
```

according to the doc, i have to use

```
_cb.set_group(&self, _cb1 : Some<&impl IsA<CheckButton>>);
```

but the compiler does not agree

```
_cb.set_group(&self, _cb1 : Some<&impl IsA<CheckButton>>);
                                ^ expected identifier
```

What's wrong?

I must say that I'am not yet very used to rust programing

Comment: Try with `_cb.set_group (Some (&_cb1));`

Comment: it's working, thank's a lot!!